# How to install openSSL 1.1 on AWS EMR?

Tags: openssl, amazon-emr, python-3.10

I am using a boostrap file to install python 3.10 for an EMR project running Pyspark. Python 3.10 needs openSSL 1.1 or greater to work with, but EMR has OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips (running command `openssl version`) and I'm unable to upgrade it.

I tried to use yum to install my required version:
`sudo yum install -y openssl11-devel <+_some_other_packages>`

But EMR has some repository priority protections that stop me from installing version 1.1:

```
13 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package gcc-7.3.1-15.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 2:tar-1.26-35.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gzip-1.5-10.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package wget-1.14-18.amzn2.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.82-24.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bzip2-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.6-13.amzn2.0.3 will be installed
---> Package libffi-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.13-18.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package openssl11-devel.x86_64 1:1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.15 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: 1:openssl11-devel-1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.15.x86_64 conflicts openssl-devel
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Then, I tried using the above suggestion, using the flag *--skip-broken* and disabling priorities checks:

`sudo yum install -y --disableplugin=priorities --skip-broken openssl11-devel <+ some other packages>`

And the log says it skips version 1.1 because of dependency problems:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bzip2-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.6-13.amzn2.0.3 will be installed
---> Package libffi-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.13-18.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package openssl11-devel.x86_64 1:1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.15 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: 1:openssl11-devel-1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.15.x86_64 conflicts openssl-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl11-devel.x86_64 1:1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.15 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bzip2-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.6-13.amzn2.0.3 will be installed
---> Package libffi-devel.x86_64 0:3.0.13-18.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    1:openssl11-devel-1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.15.x86_64 from amzn2-core
```

Finnaly, I tried to uninstall the current version 1.0 before installing the new version 1.1:

`sudo yum remove openssl`

And the log says it's erased after a dependencies check:

```
================================================================================
 Package                  Arch   Version               Repository          Size
================================================================================
Removing:
 openssl                  x86_64 1:1.0.2k-24.amzn2.0.7 installed          830 k
Removing for dependencies:
 authconfig               x86_64 6.2.8-30.amzn2.0.2    installed          2.2 M
 cloud-init               noarch 19.3-46.amzn2.0.1     installed          3.2 M
 ec2-instance-connect     noarch 1.1-19.amzn2          installed           23 k
 perl-IO-Socket-SSL       noarch 1.94-7.amzn2.0.1      @amzn2-core        216 k
 perl-Net-HTTP            noarch 6.06-2.amzn2          @amzn2-core         51 k
 perl-XML-LibXML          x86_64 1:2.0018-5.amzn2.0.2  @amzn2-core        940 k
 perl-XML-SAX             noarch 0.99-9.amzn2          @amzn2-core        125 k
 perl-libwww-perl         noarch 6.05-2.amzn2          @amzn2-core        487 k
 platform-startup-install noarch 1.17.0-1              @emr-platform-repo 2.0 k
 python-jwcrypto          noarch 0.4.2-1.amzn2         installed          249 k
 python2-cryptography     x86_64 1.7.2-2.amzn2         installed          2.6 M
 python2-oauthlib         noarch 2.0.1-8.amzn2.0.1     installed          780 k
 rng-tools                x86_64 6.8-3.amzn2.0.5       installed          102 k
 system-lsb               x86_64 4.1-27.amzn2.3.6      @amzn2-core        0.0  
 system-lsb-languages     x86_64 4.1-27.amzn2.3.6      @amzn2-core        814  

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Remove  1 Package (+15 Dependent packages)
```

But the log stopps here, the bootstrap freezes at this point for one hour until it fails. I can't see if it tries to install the version 1.1 (which come after this step).

So my question is: how to install/upgrade the current version of OpenSSL to 1.1 on EMR to run pyhton 3.10?

My bootstrap file is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.6

echo
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Removing SSL"
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo
echo "Current SSL version:"
openssl version

sudo yum update -y
sudo yum remove openssl

echo
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Installing OpenSSL"
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y --disableplugin=priorities --skip-broken gcc openssl11-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel tar gzip wget make

echo "New SSL version:"
openssl version

echo
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Installing Python ${PYTHON_VERSION}"
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz
tar xzf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz
cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}
./configure --enable-optimizations
make install
make altinstall prefix=~/local  # specify local installation directory
ln -s ~/local/bin/python3.10 ~/local/bin/python
cd ..
```

Comment: `sudo yum remove openssl` will probably break everything that depends on OpenSSL in the OS.  Why are you trying to remove `openssl` when the conflict is with `openssl-devel`?  And why aren't you installing the `openssl11` package to get the OpenSSL 1.1.1 binaries?

Answer (score 1):

I tackled a similar problem while installing a python 3.10 in a dockerfile based on EMR emr-on-eks/spark/emr-6.14.0 image.

Here are the steps:

### Install required libraries for Amazon Linux 2.

```
yum install -y git wget gcc make patch zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel \
         readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl11 openssl11-devel tk-devel libffi-devel xz-devel
```

Most important here: openssl11 and openssl11-devel. And do not install openssl-devel.

### Install Python from sources

```
PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.13    
curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz
cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}
./configure --enable-optimizations
make altinstall
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

By using make altinstal you preserve python installation coming with OS in /usr/bin/python. With altinstall python is installed separately into usr/local/bin/. You can refer to new python version with python3.10 and pip3.10 for pip (of course replace 3.10 with appropriate version of python you want to install)

Alternatively you can install python version as a default one with command `make install` instead of `make altinstall`. In this case python will be installed in /usr/bin/python